# Xamarin IOS UITableViewController RowSelected navigate to UIViewController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have UITableViewController. When user clicks to cell I need to open another ViewController. Here is my code:

public partial class CCreateOrderOrderType : UITableViewController
    {
        private List orderTypes;
        private LoadingOverlay loadingOverlay;
        public CCreateOrderOrderType (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

```
    public CCreateOrderOrderType (List<OrderType> orderTypes){
        this.orderTypes = orderTypes;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad(){
        TableView.Source = new OrderTypeTableSource (this, orderTypes);
    }
}

public class OrderTypeTableSource : UITableViewSource {

    private CCreateOrderOrderType owner;
    private List<OrderType> orderTypes;
    private string cellIdentifier = "orderGroupCI";

    public OrderTypeTableSource(CCreateOrderOrderType owner, List<OrderType> orderTypes){
        this.owner = owner;
        this.orderTypes = orderTypes;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section){
        return orderTypes.Count;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
        OrderType item = orderTypes[indexPath.Row];
        if (cell == null)
        { 
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, cellIdentifier);
            cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = item.orderTypeName;
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator; 
        }
        return cell;
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        CCreateOrderC clientOrderCreate = owner.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("CCreateOrderC") as CCreateOrderC;
        clientOrderCreate.selectedOrderType = orderTypes [indexPath.Row];
        if (clientOrderCreate != null) {
            owner.NavigationController.PushViewController (clientOrderCreate, true);
        }
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
    }
}
```

But I have Null pointer exception on first line. What's wrong?

Comment: There is some cyrillic text in your question, could you edit it out to make it clearer ? :D

Comment: @Zil, Sorry, i removed these sybols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : I Didn't know you where in a source class, not in controller.

Simple steps to work around this. Not ultra clean but that will do the trick for now :

1. Get the storyboard : `UIStoryboard.FromName("main", NSBundle.MainBundle);`

Here, "main" is the name of the storbyoard. Check the filename of your .storyboard file.

2. Get the controller from that storyboard, using `.InstantiateViewController ("CCreateOrderC") as CCreateOrderC;`  which you are already doing just fine.
3. Make sure that it's not null, you're doing fine too.
4. Push that controller on the current navigation controller.

Since you dont' have it here, you can pass it as a public property (that is the "not super clean" part).

Simply add a public property on top of your class, that is `public UINavigationController CurrentNavigationController`,

and where you create that tableview source, simply do

`mySource.CurrentNavigationController = this.navigationcontroller`

Now that you have the navigation, you can push it, just like you did, in the `RowSelected`,

`CurrentNavigationController.PushViewController(theVcYouInstantiatedWithTheStoryboard);`

PREVIOUS ANSWER BEFORE EDIT

What the null pointer is saying is, " you're executing code on something that is null ".

I'm betting "parentController" is null, and you can't call code on null objects.  That alone should answer your question and help you move forward into discovering what went wrong :)

Good thing is, I'm pretty sure you don't need that `parentController` anyway.

I suggest you replace `parentController` by `this`.

Also, if you're using storyboard, you could use a `segue` which is almost zero code (you could remove all lines!).

Here is how to do it :

In storyboard, simply drag & drop from Controller A to controller B using right clic or ctrl + clic (origin => destination). Then select the arrow that appeared, and give it a unique name. For example `FromAToB` and in code, call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` from `this`, and give it the segue name from storyboard (`FromAToB`) as a NSString parameter.

That's it :)

You can override `prepareForSegue`in your controller if you need to pass some data around, but that's another topic.

Please leave a comment below if you still have an issue or need more clarification somewhere :)

Comment: I posted my full class

Comment: Ooooh you're not in a controller ! :P well that changes everything

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a way around it. It's not exactly the cleanest, but it'll work.